# Custom formatting of a field in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint list. One of the fields in it(called DocNumber) is the document number including version. It will look like this *ESI-1234-1.0*

Basically the rule is, it should start with the text *ESI-*, then a number, followed by another hipen(-), followed by version number, then a dot(.), and a subversion number
How do i write the 'Column validation' for this. I'm using Sharepoint Online(365 I guess), so there's a placeholder in field level settings to write this formula. I searched online but the syntax is so difficult that I'm finding it hard to customize the formula -

I need something like this, but i don't want to indicate position because the numbers there could be of any length(its a serial number, currently we are at 1600, so we should support 1 to 5 digits atleast and version could be any number from 1 to 99)

```
=AND(
    IF(ISERROR(FIND("ESI-",DocNumber,1)),FALSE,(FIND("ESI-",DocNumber)=1)),
    IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",DocNumber,4)),FALSE,(FIND("-",DocNumber,4)=4)))
```

Thankyou for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the formula property of column You may use JSON structure like this:

```
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": {
        "operator": "+",
        "operands": [
          "ESI-",
          "[$ID]",
          "-",
          "[$_UIVersionString]"
        ]
      }
    }
```

here we make a custom view in a div HTML element with text inside. The Text is static string "ESI-" then we add ID column then we add "-" then we add version number column as string

the result should be something like this
[image]
... I hope this will be of any help

Comment: Hello Adam, I used the same but I'm getting the error on saving it. I'm pasting this directly under column's custom validation formula. Do I need to define those variables somewhere (ID & UIVersionString). I would like user to enter full data at once in one field rather than capturing number and version in sepearet fields in the UI page

Comment: what is the error You are having? the ID and UIVersionString are OOTB field that are present in every document library so there is no need to create them. As for the second part - maybe i misunderstood the requirements. I thought You are looking for a solution to present this data with as less operations from user as possible. And since ID and Version fields are added always automatically by SharePoint then this seemed fine. Are You looking to somehow set a mask on a field so that the user may enter value only in this format ESI-XX-XX.XX ?

Comment: Yes that's corrrect. I want to ensure the value in this field is of this format ESI-XXXX-y.z

Comment: ok, are You using modern UI and it is a must, or You may use classic UI for this library. If it is possible to use classic UI, then You may always use JSLink and override default behavior of any field with javascript which executes on pre render. After that You may use a maks on the filed. Link to mask example -> http://pawansatope.blogspot.com/2012/02/input-mask-on-textbox-in-sharepoint.html ; link to jsLink example to override column https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37332.sharepoint-2013-working-with-field-template-using-jslink.aspx